# this keyword's meaning inside a class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to understand how the `this` keyword works in JS, especially what the `this` keyword exactly represents when you use it inside a class, but not inside any nested functions. Please help me understand exactly why I get an error when I modify this first paragraph of code to the second paragraph of code.

```
console.log(this);
  constructor () {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
var tiger = new Animal();
```

This will output: `Window {} and Animal {}` as I want, in the console.

```
console.log(this);
class Animal {
    var that = this; // addition
  constructor () {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
var tiger = new Animal();
console.log(tiger.that) // addition
```

This will output `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in the console. I believe the cause of this error, is the line `var that = this;` but I don't understand why, I had hypothesized, the variable `that` would be equal to `Window {} or Animal {}`.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect, you need to move `var that` inside your `constructor()`

Comment: I'm assuming you're getting the error on the `console.log(tiger.that)` line, because `var that = this;` is not visible outside of the class.

Comment: @Mr. Alien The point is, I don't want to move it into a nested method, like the constructor. I wanted to see what the `this` referenced when outside a method but still inside a class.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The error would be there regardless of `console.log(tiger.that)`. I just tried removing it, and the error still remained.

Comment: @Arshaan You cannot do that

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the second example, `that` is a local variable in the scope of `class Animal`. When you declare a variable with the `var` keyword, it is only declared in the current scope. It is undefined in any code outside of that class.

For more information, check the MSDN article on [Variable Scope in Javascript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer I needed. I didn't fully grasp the rules of the language. I assumed, if I instantiated the class, and then tried to access a property, I could display it.

Comment: It's invalid syntax, scope has nothing to do with this. You cannot declare variables inside class like that

Answer (score 0):

What you tried is not valid syntax. Check [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) for reference.

Comment: Please note that link-only answers [are discouraged on stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please explain *why* this isn't valid syntax in your own words and how it could be fixed to be correct syntax.

Comment: @Philipp I get your point and generally agree, but not this time.  It was 1 line of code being misplaced and with a pretty semantic error.  This is not an answer with a link implying `hey, take a look at the whole Javascript documentation` this is a link to an explicit documentation article showing the correct syntax for the Class expression, and if the question is manly about syntax, simply pointing to a compressed documentation article is a valid answer (or at least would be if I was the one asking).

Answer (score -1):

You need to move your `var that = this;` to `constructor()`. You cannot declare `class` specific properties outside of a method.

```
console.log(this);
class Animal {
  constructor () {
    var that = this; // addition
    console.log(this);
  }
}
var tiger = new Animal();
console.log(tiger.that) // addition
```

Comment: or (what he most likely desired): `this.that = this;` otherwise `that` is only visible inside the constructor (or should be)

Comment: This is what I misunderstood when writing the question, "You cannot declare class specific properties outside of a method." Thanks for the explanation.